# Changing the min. SDK version of an Android app

Tags: android, sdk, target

How to change the version of android application. i did entire code in Android 2.2 version, if i want to install the apk in 2.1 version, it getting parse error. How to change the versions of application. I dont know how to solve this issue. pls guide me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using eclipse it's very easy

go in eclipse project explorer

then right click on properties

select android from tree view

select your appropriate version.

and then in 
in menifest file change 
minsdk to 2.1

Answer (score 2):

If you are using eclipse change value in manifest and build target in project configuration (Right click on project->Properties->Android-> Select that one which you need.

You have to also know that there can be some problems because of different version.

Check also this one [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/compatibility.html)